# Sum of infinite squared terms when all sum to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a question regarding the following case. I am pretty confident that the answer is zero but I need some proof:

Assume $0<w_{i}<1$ , $i=1, \ldots, n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}=1$ $\forall n$. What can we say regarding the following limit?: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}^{2}$$   I think it equals to zero. Furthermore in the special case where $w_{i}=\frac{1}{n}$ then, the proof is easy and it does indeed yield an answer of zero.

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: Your claim is true only if (and if) $\lim_{n\to\infty} \max_{i=1}^n w_i = 0$.  In other words, it's false in general.

Comment: the notation is badly misleading.  I think you mean to say that for each $n\in \mathbb N$ you have a collection $\{w_i(n)\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $0<w_i(n)<1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nw_i(n)=1$.  If that's all we have, then your desired claim is false (for the reasons given in the posted solutions).  If you have more constraints on the $w_i(n)$ then you should share them.

Comment: @Nitin Why can't I? For example $n=4$ and $w_{1}=w_{2}=w_{3}=w_{4}=\frac{1}{4}$ without $w_{2}$ , $w_{3}$ and $w_{4}$ being zero.. I think I might not be describing correctly the problem.

Comment: My mistake. I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your "special case" suggests that you will allow the values of the $w_i$ to be different for different values of $n$.

If that's true, your assertion is wrong. Just let $w_1 = 1/2$ and the rest of the $w_i = 1/2(n-1)$.

Comment: If I let $w_{1}=0.5$ and use say $n=3$ then the condition I stated $\sum_{i=1}^{3}w_{i}=1$ is violated. Yes I am allowing different values of the $w$s but they have to add up to 1 for any $n$. The special case that all $w$s are equal reduces to all $w$s being equal to $\frac{1}{n}$. It can be the case that the $w$s are not equal, but for any $n$ they should add up to 1.

Comment: @leo They do add up to $1$ in this example!  The condition is not violated, so why do you say it is?

Comment: @Erick Wong I thought you meant 0.5*(n-1) and not $\frac{1}{2(n-1)}$ so my bad. Your example for $n=3$ yields $w_{1}=0.5$, $w_{2}=0.25$, and $w_{3}=0.25$. What's wrong about that? It is just one example with $n=3$ that all conditions are satisfied. I am not sure I understand your point.. My special case refers to the case that one wants to force equal $w$s, then you are forced to set them all equal to $\frac{1}{n}$ to comply. The case of unequal $w$s is what I do not know.. $w$s change for different values of $n$ so that they are forced to comply with the conditions.

Comment: @leo Have you tried reading this answer?  Apparently not, if you are still undecided about the unequal case.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the delay, everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

if $w_1=w_2=\frac{1}{2}$ and $w_i=0$ for $i\geq 3$ then the limit is *not* 0 (but $\frac{1}{2}$).

what you have is that $1=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}w_i\geq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{w_i}^2\geq 0$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the comments, maybe I was not clear enough: The argument of $w_{1}=w_{2}=0.5$ is irrelevant and would hold only if $n=2$. I mean that whatever the value of $n$ the terms add up to 1 for that particular $n$.

Comment: it is also possible to get a counter example by $w_1=w_2=\frac{1}{4}$ and $w_i=\frac{1}{2\cdot(n-2)}$ for $i\geq 3$ that satisfies $0<w_i<1$.

Comment: For example the special case I was referring to is $w_{i}=\frac{1}{n}$, $\forall i$. Hence you would have: $lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i}^{2}=lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{2}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1=lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}1/n=0$

Comment: yes, but your special case is only a special case and the case i just posted is *another* specal case that gives a counter example. (or am i wrong?!)

Comment: It is a counterxample of what? I am  a bit lost regarding your conclusion of the limit. Also in your first counterxample you assume that some $w_{i}$s are zero which cannot be the case. In the second counterxample i do not understand why is this a counterxample for something...

Comment: it's a counterexample giving $0\neq\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2>\frac{1}{2}>0$ (actually it is nearly the same as the one that Ethan Bolker posted)

Comment: In your second counterxample where you state $w_{i}=\frac{1}{2(n-1)}$ for $i\geq 3$ and $w_{1}=w_{2}=\frac{1}{4}$ then for say $n=10$ the condition that $\sum_{i=1}^{10} {w_{i}}=1$ is violated right? So this is not a counterexample.

Comment: this is because implicitely the notation you introduced in your question lets $w_i$ depend on $n$. (Otherwise that would give a contradiction just by considering $n=1\Rightarrow w_1=1$ and $n=2\Rightarrow w_2>0\Rightarrow w_1=1-w_2<1$)

Comment: Yes I see the paradox of $n=1$. This would imply that for $w_{1}=1$ which cannot be the case in my problem. Can we restrict it to cases where $n>2$. Actually $n$ in my problem is a sample size that is why I want to explore the limit for $n$ tending to infinity.

Comment: If $n=2$ then $w_1+w_2=1$. For $n=3$ we have $w_3>1$ and $1=w_1+w_2+w_3=1+w_3>1$. Do you see the problem now? We could play that game for all $n$.^^

Comment: Ok there is a missunderstanding. The $n=3$ is completely different and independent from the $n=2$ case. It does not mean that after you set $n=2$ then the $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ remain the same as with the $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ that you would have for say $n=3$. Every $n$ case yields different $w$s.

Comment: This is exactly what I stated in my 4th comment and this is also what all the people assumed who provided you with other counter examples.

Answer (score 0):

$$
w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_n = 1
$$

where each $0 <w_i < 1$. Squaring both side

$$
w_1^2 + w_2^2 + \cdots + w_n^2 = 1 - 2 \sum_{i \ne j}w_i w_j
$$

Now if $n \to \infty$ it means that the sum of infinite number of small positive quantities between 0 and 1 is equal to one. Hence there will be infinitely many of them arbitrarily close or equal to zero.But some of them may not be arbitrarily close. Hence $\sum_{i \ne j}w_i w_j$ cannot be determined explicitly but you know that it has be a positive quantity. Hence $n \to \infty$,

$$
w_1^2 + w_2^2 + \cdots + w_n^2 \le 1
$$

Comment: We can be a little more quantitative than this: let $k=\max_{i=1}^n w_i$ (which implicitly depends on $n$).  Then it's easy to see the sum of squares is bounded between $k^2$ and $k$.  The lower bound can be strengthened a bit by Cauchy-Schwartz, but it's already enough to characterize when the sum goes to $0$.

Answer (score -1):

Here's something stronger than a counterexample: take $w_i = (1/2)^i$.  Then $0 < w_i < 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i$ is strictly *less* than $1$ for all $n$.  But $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n w_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i^2 = 1/3$.

Your question is very poorly phrased as you are not expressing clearly the dependence of $w_i$ on $n$.  This is likely the source of your confusion about other people's counterexamples: perhaps you are making additional assumptions on $w_i$ that are not written anywhere in your question.

Comment: @ Erick Wong Maybe you are right that I am not being clear enough and maybe you can help me more with the notation. When one sets a value of $n$ this means that one will have $n$ values of $w$s. So for exampe if $n=5$ then you must have $w_{1}$, $w_{2}$, $w_{3}$, $w_{4}$ and $w_{5}$ for which you know that all sum up to exactly 1 and $0<w_{i}<1$ for $i=1,\ldots,n=5$. I hope that is clearer and thank your time and comments.

Comment: @leo My point is that even if the $w_i$s sum up to **less** than one, the sum of $w_i^2$ can still be much greater than $0$.  But you seem to be wearing blinders against seeing counterexamples.